# How to split some of the minus operators based on a condition?

Tags: python, regex

I was working of a mathematical formula ,I need to split operands for the processing,

I was using `re.split('\+|\-|\*|\/', Formula)` function in python to split the formula into operands.

But I have one notation **wa(A,[-126,-123,-120,-117,-114,-111,-108,-105,-102,-99,-96,-93,-90,-87,-84,-81,-78])-B-C-D** which I couldn't split using the above regex as its splits the number in the list too(its taking - before 126 also for spliting)

Is there any way we can using regex and split into **['wa(A,[-126,-123,-120,-117,-114,-111,-108,-105,-102,-99,-96,-93,-90,-87,-84,-81,-78])','B','C','D']** , or I need to loop through the expression and write the logic?

Comment: You have `5-123` as second list element:... why does the subtraction disappear in the desired result? What should happen when that occurs in the input?

Comment: Your regex includes all four arithmetic operators but you example contains only minus signs. Is there some reason for that? You've also left out all quotation marks in the example and desired result.

Comment: Hmmm. Bit disappointing that comments don't get replies.

Comment: sorry @trincot , My bad, it was supposed to be -123, That was a typo. I can understand How that can be confusing, I really appreciate you trying to help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an alternation to match either word characters followed by an opening till closing parenthesis, or match any char except a hyphen.

```
\w+\([^()]+\)|[^\s+/*-]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBpqbE/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/niu6Um).

```
import re

pattern = r"\w+\([^()]+\)|[^\s+/*-]+"
s = "wa(A,[-126,5-123,-120,-117,-114,-111,-108,-105,-102,-99,-96,-93,-90,-87,-84,-81,-78])-B-C-D"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['wa(A,[-126,5-123,-120,-117,-114,-111,-108,-105,-102,-99,-96,-93,-90,-87,-84,-81,-78])', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```